# How do I assert that the result only has what I searched for?

Tags: automation, protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

I'm writing a test in protractor where I search for a user on a page and assert that I only get the result of the user I searched for. I know how to assert that the result has the user I searched for, but how do I assert that the result doesn't have any other users in the result? I'm new to automation testing and would appreciate any help in this.

The results are displayed in cards with the user name and Image. There could be more than one user with the same name.

Comment: more info is needed - html code, protractor code, what you tried etc

Answer (score 0):

If you have cards you can try to find count of this cards. If it more than you need you can fail this test.